# Some files under my CATALINA_BASE folder not copied to Idea's CATALINA_BASE folder

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ Idea 2017.1 (but I tested it on version 14 as well), the OS is CentOS 6.7.

When I start Tomcat from Idea it uses **%USER_HOME%/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/system/tomcat/Unnamed_my-application/** as **CATALINA_BASE**.

During Tomcat server configuration I've been asked to specify 2 folders: Tomcat home & Tomcat base directory.

[image]

The selected Tomcat base directory contains 2 files under **bin** directory: setenv.sh & server.properties. The **setenv.sh** is copied to Idea's defined CATALINA_BASE folder while the other file not.

No errors appear in idea.log file.
Both files has the same permissions.

Why the other file isn't copied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat integration copies bin/setenv.sh|bat file and conf/, logs/, work/ folders from  to IDEA CATALINA_BASE directory like "%USER_HOME%/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/system/tomcat/Unnamed_my-application".

As a workaround, try to move /bin/server.properties to /conf subfolder and then rerun Tomcat Run/Debug configuration.

Comment: Hi Michael, do you have a documentation reference?